# retriving data from a Mysql database using PDO based on users input from select options of a form (Using PDO method for Mysql)

Tags: pdo

can anybody explain me please what each line of this following code is doing?? One of the doubts is commented too. Also please explain what each line is doing.

```
$sql = "SELECT album_name
FROM albums
WHERE artist_id=?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute(array($_POST['artist']))) // Why if statement here??
{
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
printf("Album: %s<br />", $row['album_name']); 
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
}
}
```

Comment: The if condition makes sure there is a successful response from the execution of the query before proceeding with the while loop over the resulting rows.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Hi, Thank you very much! :) What actually does, prepare('queryWIDplaceHolder') method do, to the query with a place holder is passed as parameter??

Comment: `prepare` gets the query ready for execution. One benefit is you can use prepared statements like you are, and another benefit is you can use the query over again with less overhead. This benefit is real nice for INSERT'ing many rows of information.